# Isn't detecting any collisions Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to get collisions to work in unity, and they just arent seeming to work. Heres my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Die : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
        if(col.gameObject.name == "Lava") {
            Debug.Log("Death");
        }
    }
}
```

Attached to this player object (empty obj):
[image]

With this capsule inside:

[image]
And the lava object:

[image]

I have tried to use rigidbodies and followed many tutorials on Youtube, but nothing has worked. Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: you have not metion colision criteria.. collision requires physics, requires a rigidbody please read up on collisions

Comment: @BugFinder tried that, but it still didnt work im just trying to find a direct answer

Comment: that is a direct answer.. die probably needs to be on the same object as the rb and collider

Comment: ok imma try that

Comment: @BugFinder works except it has a weird effect on the player, how do i just make it so the rigidbody does nothing except serve collisions

Comment: @frigidus "make it so the rigidbody does nothing except serve collisions" That's what the option `Is Trigger` is for

Comment: Previous comment is a bit hasty.  You actually want to set the rigidbodies [`IsKinematic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) to prevent physics from affecting your object but still receiving collision events.

Comment: both previous comments arent working, i dont really know what im doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things you might want to know:

- A `CharacterController` component should **not** be used with a `Rigidbody`, - rather, it's effectively a replacement for it.
- A `CharacterController` works differently to a collider. It doesn't recieve any collision events, but it emits the `[OnControllerColliderHit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.OnControllerColliderHit.html)` event on its object if it collides with a collider during its `.move()` method.
- Check out https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/character-control-section.html for further information about using a `CharacterController`.

That said, if memory serves, you *should* be able to completely fix your problem by simply changing your `Die` class like so - assuming that the lava object won't be moving:

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class Die : MonoBehaviour
{
    // invoked if the controller collider collided with something during the .move method
    void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        if(hit.gameObject.name == "Lava")
        {
            Debug.Log("Death");
        }
    }
}
```

**edit:** alternatively, you could implement it as follows:

1. Edit your `Die` class as follows:

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class Die : MonoBehaviour
{
    // called by a killer to get this to die
    public void PlsDie()
    {
        Debug.Log("Death");
    }
}
```

2. Create the following class

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class HitMeAndYouWillDie: MonoBehaviour
{
  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
  {
    // see if the thing we collided with has a 'Die' object
    Die thisWillDie = col.gameObject.GetComponentInParent<Die>();
    if (thisWillDie != null)
    {   // if it did, get it to die
        thisWillDie.PlsDie();
    }
  }
}
```

3. Add a `HitMeAndYouWillDie` component to your 'Lava' object.

Comment: you are the greatest person in the entire world thank you so muchhhhhhhh